# copying a file from documents folder to home folder using cp command

Tags: command-line, 15.04, execute-command

I am trying to learn how to copy a from one folder to other using command prompt using 'cp' command,file is getting copied from "home" folder to "documents" folder but i am unable to copy from "documents" folder to "home" folder.Can someone explain why?

Comment: What do you mean with `home` folder? Your `home` folder, eg `/home/identicon` or `/home`

Comment: Is there any error output?

Comment: no error but another copy of file with name as home is appearing in documents folder

Comment: home means /home

Comment: "b.txt" name is changed to "home" not /home

Comment: If i tried to send a file "file.txt" from "documents" folder to "music" folder a file named "music" with data of "file.txt" is appearing in "documents" folder.

Comment: Don't make `/home` a garbage.. It's the designated place for individual users home directories..

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and post the **exact** commands you are typing, with **exact** capitalization: otherwise we can only guess what the issue is.

Comment: What heemayl and steeldriver said; if you really want to copy stuff into `/home/`, anyway, A.B.'s answer or aairey's comment (`sudo cp /home/identicon/Documents/file_name /home` or `sudo cp b.txt /home` if `~/Documents/` is the current working directory) would have worked, so you've probably misspelled something like the capitalization, as steeldriver pointed out.

Comment: Please provide the actual commands or this will be riddled with comments and the answers will be partially guesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what your command actually looks like.

The following would work:

```
cp /home/$USER/Documents/file /home/$USER
```

Or as @kos suggested:

```
cp ~/Documents/file ~/
```

Comment: This will copy the whole `~/Documents/` folder to `~/`; also maybe use the shorthanded `cp ~/Documents/file ~/`, this way the command will also work right away once copy-pasted

Comment: Notebook-PC:~/Documents$ cp    b.txt     /Home   is the command

Comment: `/home` is not writabel by a normal user. My guess is you want to copy it to _your own_ homefolder, which is `/home/yourusername`. The command is then `cp b.txt ~/` (see above). If you do want to copy it in just plain `/home`, you will have to run `sudo cp b.txt /home`.

Comment: @identicon Linux systems are case sensitive, so you want `sudo cp b.txt /home`

Comment: @aairey Please use $USER (it will  change the command into the user used so tends to work for all of us). Or of course "~"

Answer (score 0):

To copy from your documents folder try:

```
cp filenameHere /home/$USER
```

For example, assuming I am located at the Documents folder:

```
/home/$USER/Documents
```

And I want to copy the file: foo.txt to my home folder:

```
cp foo.txt /home/$USER
```

If you are not currently on the Documents foler, you must cd to it first:

```
cd /home/$USER/Documents
```

Then you can do `ls` to list your files, remember, the terminal and linux commands are case sensitive:

```
ls
```

After the files are listed, use the `cp` command to copy to the location you want.

Comment: it is creating a file named home in documents folder itself

Comment: To do that do: 

1 >> home.txt 

where 1 is the content of the file, this is a fast way, so you can create any file, with any title if no file with the same name is already on the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy documents into the `/home` folder without `sudo` rights. To do that, use this command

```
sudo cp /home/$USER/Documents/file_name /home
```

or to save the permissions (thx  [@kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos))

```
sudo cp --preserve=mode,ownership /home/$USER/Documents/file_name /home
```

---

If you meant *your* `home` folder, than use

```
cp /home/$USER/Documents/file_name ~
```

or

```
cp /home/$USER/Documents/file_name /home/$USER/
```

Comment: not working with sudo also

Comment: And if one wants to preserve permissions / ownership: `sudo cp --preserve=mode,ownership /home/identicon/Documents/file_name /home`

Answer (score 0):

First go to the location from where the file is to copied using the `cd` command.Then:

```
cp "foldername" -R ~/"foldername"
```

Comment: This will copy recursively all the directories / files in `foldername` in `~/foldername`

Comment: Ok i am sorry I mistook the question for the abovesaid. Yes it will.